# Intelligent way to manage a project with many modules, using version control

Tags: python, svn, version-control

I'm gradually porting a Classic ASP project to Python and HTML. This porting is intended to create a core web application that I can extend with different (or shared) modules and customizations for each customer.
The actual state is an application based on a python core, a python customer project and a bridge componente that serves to web clients the appropriate file.

Imagine this scenario:
CORE
 |_ Customer 1: CORE + Module A
 |_ Customer 2: CORE + Module B
 |_ Customer 3: CORE + Module A + Module B (A and B are not separates modules but insist on some shared files)

Suppose now to have this further requests:
1) Fix a bug in Module A and propagate it for Customer 1 and 3
2) Add a Customer 4 with a Module C, but A and B also

My dream would be to have a versioning system (or something similar) that let me move through "branches" but can be automatically tell me what files I have to update and work on to develop only on Module A, or else Module A+B together.

An alternative way would be to develop each module on a master branch, and then do a lot of "if else" to serve the correct "merge" of the modules, but the more modules I will develop , the more will increase the time parsing, the more difficult will be the maintaining of my source code.

Some ideas?

Comment: Is each customer deployed separately? Does the customer get the code? In that case, the core project would be one repo, and each customer a separate repo. You'd do a python setup.py build for each repo and use python wheel to handle dependencies.

Comment: Hy tdelaney! Each customer has a separate deploy but doesn't get the code: the projects is a web application, so the customer uses it through a browser and sees only the resulting html. At this time, there is a core repo and many customers repo but the problem is: if two or more customer share a module, and this module is in the customer repo, I have to mantain and fix in each customer repo, which is a waste of time and money.